# Regex Capture Group substring

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++, substring

Trying to use Regex in `Notepad++`.  I'd like to have the following happen:

**FirstName: Jonathan**

Replaced to:

**FirstName: Jona**

I've tried the following:

Find Statement

> FirstName:(.*)

Replace Statement:

> FirstName:\1

In order to put it into a captured group.  But now I need that captured group to be `truncated/substring` so it's just the first **four** characters.  When I do the replace, it replaces the full string just fine, but I'm not clear how to get just the first four characters of the capture group.  I've tried `(.*){4}` but that returns nothing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there is a way to access just a part of a matched group, but you can instead only match the part you want.

Your new find statement would capture only the first 4 characters but still match the rest:

```
FirstName: (.{4}).*?$
```

Which translates to "find the string 'FirstName: ', then remember the next four characters, and then keep going till the end of the line."

Your replace statement would be almost the same as before (I included a space after FirstName):

```
FirstName: \1
```

Comment: Note that if there are less than 4 characters after "FirstName: " then this regex won't match and it will be ignored altogether, which is the same as capturing `(.{1,4})` and re-inserting it. In fact the `.*?` could be replaced with `.+?` and examples with exactly 4 characters after "FirstName: " would be ignored as well. But for most cases (barring case insensitivity and other weirdness) these would be equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to go:

- Find what: `(FirstName:.{1,4}).*?$`
- Replace with: `$1`

Answer (score 0):

If it's at the beginning of the line *and* line oriented,
or the only line item, this would work.

Find:  `(?im)^[^\S\r\n]*(firstname:)[^\S\r\n]*([a-z]{0,4}|.{0,4}).*`
Replace: `FirstName $1`

If it's in the middle of the string, it would take more effort.
Have to see some examples of that because would have to use pseudo-anchors.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern will only bother processing lines with excess length to truncate.

My pattern will not only outperform the other answers in terms of step-count/efficiency, but it will also not bother with any references or text in the replacement field.

Use this: ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vMzP9d/1))

Find: `FirstName: .{4}\K.+`
Replace: *[nothing]*

*Note, the `\K` means "start matching from this point".  The `.+` will stop at the end of each line.